# hibernate jpa suitable annotaion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

let's suppose that i have two entities A and B

entity A:

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="A")

    public class A  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idA")
    private int idA;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<B> listofB ;

///GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

entity B:

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="B")

    public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idB")
    private int idB;


///GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

Now when i run this code , hibernate will automatically generate a table in the database. The table's name is A_B and it contains the id of A and the id of B,

```
*********************
* Table    A_B      *
*********************
*A_idA * listofB_idB*
*      *            * 
*********************
```

But what i want to do actually is to focre hibernate to generate a table with a numeric  value in every line , and i want it to be considered in every new line , i mean i want a table like this one

```
    *****************************
    *        Table    A_B       *
    *****************************
    *A_idA * listofB_idB* Value *
    *      *            *       *
    *****************************
```

how should i proceed ???

Comment: If you want a relationship as a first class entity you will need  to create that entity.

Comment: I can't understand. What is the column "Value" in your desired A_B table?

Comment: @JBNizet: The colum value is column of integers...

Comment: That does explain anything. What, from your entities shown above, would this column contain? How about explaining what you rally want to do, with a more concrete example than A, B and Value?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: But Value is a column of integers ...!!

Comment: @JBNizet : Well i just wanted to simplify the problem , in reality entity A is an Order form , entity B is equipment and The column value is the number of equipements in every Order form.

Comment: OK. So you simply need an additional `OrderedEquipment` entity, referencing an `Equipment` and having a `number` field. And the `Order` should have a OneToMany association with `OrderedEquipment`.

Comment: Ok but can you write OrderedEquipement Entity  in an answer so i can test it and validate it as a correct one if it's working?? thanks

Comment: That's your job. If you want me to write the code for you, my fare is 600 euros per day.

Comment: misunderstood!!! i just wanted you to earn your deserved points!!

Comment: @BellilMedSamouel: don't worry about my points. I have plenty of them already. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a new entity C

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="C")

    public class C implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="idC")
    private int idC;

    @Column(name="value")
    private int value;

    @OneToOne   
    private B b;  


///GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

And  modify the entity A to

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="A")

    public class A  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idA")
    private int idA;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<C> listofC ;

///GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

Then hibernate will generate a table named A_C